# Reserved Ampersand Character in Label Expression of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, labeling, arcgis-10.3

I have this code which works...

```
def FindLabel ([NUMBERNAME], [NUMBER], [BLOCK], [SURNUM]):
      lineone = "A:"+ [NUMBER]
      absName = "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + [NUMBERNAME] + "</FNT></CLR>"
      if [NUMBERNAME] is not None:
          return lineone + '\n' + absName + '\n' + "BLK:" + [BLOCK] + '\n' + "SEC:"+ [SURNUM]
```

However I have some field values in [NUMBERNAME] that contain the reserved ampersand character (&). If the value contains the ampersand character the label looks like this...

```
<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '5.5'>T&P RR CO</FNT></CLR>
BLK: 
SEC:
```

Versus (in this example) a label that looks like...

'T&P RR CO'

I have found this [documentation](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/text/text-formatting-tags.htm), which references this code to fix the ampersand issue....

```
 Function FindLabel ([LABELFIELD])
  NewString = Replace([LABELFIELD],"&","&amp;")  
  FindLabel = "<ITA>" & NewString & "</ITA>"
End Function
```

This is in VBScript. How would I do something similar to this using the Python parser of ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

Comment: I'm confused because you have referenced documentation for the ArcGIS Pro application on a question that seems to be written for ArcMap.

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes, the documentation referenced is for ArcGIS Pro, and yes I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1. I listed the documentation since it referenced a VBScript code that works in ArcGIS Destktop 10.3.1, however I am looking for a python parser that has the same functionality as in the VBScript example that they list. I have been pointed in the right direction, and the question was answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a similar replace method you can use:

```
def FindLabel ([NUMBERNAME], [NUMBER], [BLOCK], [SURNUM]):
      lineone = "A:" + [NUMBER]
      numName = [NUMBERNAME].replace("&", "&amp;")
      absName = "<CLR red='255'><FNT size = '14'>" + numName + "</FNT></CLR>"
      if [NUMBERNAME] is not None:
          return lineone + '\n' + absName + '\n' + "BLK:" + [BLOCK] + '\n' + "SEC:"+ [SURNUM]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for, works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
newString = string.replace("&", "&amp;")
```

Where `string` is your field with ampersand.